# Wordpress Cutsom Post Type - 700+ items

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have to deal with 700+ employees that are listed in the company address book module. I have to integrate them in an intranet that I'm developing with wordpress and I'm thinking to create a CPT called "Employee" and import all these employees here with all their information (phone, email, picture, etc) for which I'd use custom-fields.

This data must be searchable and paginated.

My question are:

- Would it be OK to use CPT for this? I mean, maybe 700+ is too much and queries will be slow?
- Would it be better instead to have a separate table "users" and deal directly with it and keep it separate from wordpress architecture?
- Any other suggestions?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'v developed something similar. Willing to test out with a sample data set if you want to see the results?

http://www.webdistortion.com/2011/12/10/ontact-a-simple-wordpress-contact-solution/